# How to index without tagging every entry

Tags: indexing

Is there a way to index a long document without having to find every entry in text? I am using `\makeindex` which requires the insertion of `\index{xyz}` after every entry in text that I want indexed.

Comment: A quick and dirty method is to wrap the text into a command, which both prints your text and the makes an entry to the index: `\newcommand{\myindex}[1]{#1\index{#1}}`, e.g. `\myindex{Einstein}` will print Einstein right there and generates the index entry `Einstein` too. However, this is a cheap 'hack' and will not work for more sophisticated index entries ;-)

Comment: And please post a MWE such that users can provide better solutions

Comment: It should be possible to automatize this with a script (in python / perl / ...) without too much effort. However a good index uses page ranges and marks definitions. Besides there are cases in which something is mentioned incidentally so that an index entry is dispensable. So it is a trade-off between convenience and quality.

Comment: If the document is already written a script (in `perl` or `awk` or ...) could implement @ChristianHupfer 's suggestion.

Comment: You should not add every occurrence of terms to the index. That is a great way to create an unhelpful index for the reader. Suppose a common term occurs on 10% of pages. That's 40 pages listed for the word in the index. It is unlikely they are all helpful and it is especially likely they are all helpful for the same questions. Either many fewer pages should be listed or the entry should be subdivided by topic.

Comment: I must admit that I have misunderstood the question unfortunately. I thought, that it is about about reducing the work need to type `word\index{word}` using logical markup; my solution below (somehow) addresses this, but not for every incidence of some term, which most probably leaves an index too big and unreadable.

Answer (score 5):

This is a quick method to insert text and a index entry simultaneously.

If the index entry is more complicated, one can use the optional argument of the command to provide a special index entry.

I called the command `\ShowTextIndex`, but this is too long, I know. If someone knows a better term, please leave a comment ;-)

I could also have simplified the non-optional argument version of the command, but I have some idea in mind, which would the whole editing useless, so I kept basically as a repetition of the optional argument version.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{imakeidx}%



\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ShowTextIndex@opt}[2][]{%
#2\index{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}%

\newcommand{\ShowTextIndex@noopt}[1]{%
#1\index{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\ShowTextIndex}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\ShowTextIndex@opt}{\ShowTextIndex@noopt}
}%
\makeatother

\makeindex

\begin{document}
This is a text about \ShowTextIndex{\textcolor{blue}{Einstein}} and his \ShowTextIndex[Theory!of relativy]{theory}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

I can provide a screen shot later on, if requested, but it shows the expected output.

More sophisticated techniques would use a keyvalue interface, in my point of view, but I do not have enough time right now.

Comment: Would it index every further mention of "Einstein" in the index? My point is to economize by not having to put in bracket every occurence of, say, "Einstein" (my book is 400 pages)

Comment: No, it would not, in this case you have to use a command, say `\Einstein`, this would be logical markup. However, this could be difficult, because you would have occurences of, say `Einstein's` , `Einsteins` etc, i.e. the grammar/semantics is important.

Comment: This reminds me of my [`idxcmds`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/idxcmds) package :)

Comment: regarding optional arguments for index commands, please note that the form `\index[xxx]{yyy}` is used by `imakeidx` to support multiple indexes (identified here by `xxx`).  it would be too bad if that facility were suppressed, since it's a very useful feature.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, you are right, I should either restrict to 'traditional' `makeidx` package or update the code. I think, the latter would be better, the first easier.

Comment: @cgnieder: Sorry, I had no idea of your package. Good to know, however.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is one of my less known packages... I doubt that anyone besides me is using it :)

Comment: @cgnieder: If at least you are using it has been worthy enough. My 'packages' are still in a rudimentary state ;-)